# Google Spreadsheet Script - Sort range by one column not working

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to sort a range in a Google Spreadsheet by the values of one column as described in [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj). The sheet `Recepten` contains 2 columns and 23 rows of data. The first row is the header row which does not need be sorted.

If I try to sort after getting the range with [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) it does not do anything. I do not get any error either.

When I try the sort after getting the range with [`getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation), it does work.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function test() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var recepten = ss.getSheetByName("Recepten");

    var nbRecepten = recepten.getLastRow();

    var sortCells = recepten.getRange(2, 1, nbRecepten-1, 2);
    //var sortCells = recepten.getRange("A2:B23");
    sortCells.sort(1);

}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried using `Logger.log(nbRecepten);`
I'd be double checking what that var is returning.
Also when using `getRange` have you manually typed in 22 instead of nbRecepten - 1

Comment: When I manually typed 22, the code did not work either.

Comment: When you go to the execution transcript, what error was given?
Are you able to share the sheet you have?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the fact that the first column (on which I want to sort) is made with a function rand(). I added a screenshot of the first 10 rows to my question.

Comment: You could add the sort to the rand function.
But as long as the values are written to the sheet, and not dynamically calculated, I think sort should work. It would be useful if you could share an example of your sheet.

Comment: I don't see any error in your code.  You'll need to reproduce the issue in a spreadsheet of just those 23 rows of data, or with the minimum amount of data.  Then it can be verified whether it's a bug or not.  If it's a bug you can report it to the issue tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)